# Safe Way To Register Users On Website

Tags: security, registration, captcha

I have my first website.  One of the first tasks I have encountered is creating a registration page to register a new user. I have concerns about "safe" ways to do this. Essentially a registration page is a window to do database inserts into a user table. I'm concerned about script kiddies getting a hold of my registration form and mercilessly pounding the database with false inserts.

A couple things I've researched and struggled with:

- Captchas: I really wanted to be able to create my site without these as from my research it sounds like they're about 20% effective at turning away bots while they are guaranteed to anger real human users. If at all possible I'd like to make captcha's be either non-existent on my site or dynamically appear if it seems I'm being scripted against.
- IP Spoofing - I toyed with the idea of checking based on IP so that if I get a lot of successive form submissions from the same IP I could give them a captcha. However, it is my understanding that it is trivial to spoof IP addresses and that checking for repeat submissions from someone who is appropriately spoofing would be ineffective.
- Registration Confirmation via Email Link - You see this a lot on forums, etc. After the user registers you send them a confirmation link with a unique token to verify they have a real email box and haven't put in a fake one (or perhaps genuinely mis-typed). While this may add some value around validating a user is "real" you have already inserted into your user table and thus script kiddies prevail at filling a database with useless information.

How do site developers prevent script kiddies from spamming their database with tons of useless users? If the assumptions I've made above are correct I don't see an effective way to prevent it. I have *toyed* with other ideas that after I think about them are all crap. The search terms I'm currently using aren't turning up many results so I apologize if this is an overplayed topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Confirmation Emails, combined with a clean up task (that deletes all registrations over x number of days which are not confirmed) will help.  You won't be able to prevent all spam registrations, but a little bit of work in the DB will help keep the table small.

Comment: Have you found that even having a value of X being as high as to be measured in the "days" category you have not had a particularly motivated script kiddie make a mess out of your database table? I could imagine the table filling quite quickly for a motivated scripter.

Comment: Marking as correct answer as it is the most complete direct answer to the question noting that what I'm after is not really possible and hence creating a self sustaining cleanup methodology is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally agreed with eliminating the `captcha` part, however you can trap some bots in a Honeypot. Make an input field which is invisible to the end-user, however still exists for bots. If the submitted form contains the `fake-field` value then ignore it, real users can't see invisible fields! :)

For example:

```
// jQuery
$("#username").hide();

// HTML
<input type="text" name="real-username">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">

// PHP
if (!empty($_REQUEST['username']))
    die('Oops!');
```

Just remember that you need to ignore the `username` field, your real username is in `real-username`.